# XSD validation - looking for some good advice

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="a">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="a1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="b">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="b1" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="c">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:element name="d">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="d1" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:attribute name="d2" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="e">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                                    <xs:element name="e1"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="e2"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="e3"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="e4"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I validate this with the w3c side: [xsd validation](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/)

And i am getting the following exception:

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 6, 25: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 25; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_a' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

What i am doing wrong?

Best regards!

Comment: Please try to find a more informative subject line. Everyone who posts on StackOverflow is looking for good advice, by definition.

Comment: Indeed you are right Michael, i will do that in my following questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making two errors:

1. The definitions of attributes must follow the definitions of child elements (not precede as in your schema).
2. `<xs:complexType>` may not contain `<xs:element>` as children

This is the corrected variant of your schema that should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="b">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="c">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:element name="d">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="e">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:element name="e1"/>
                                <xs:element name="e2"/>
                                <xs:element name="e3"/>
                                <xs:element name="e4"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="d1" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="d2" type="xs:string"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="b1" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="a1" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```